# Как вывести дата-сет только с индексами содержащимися в array?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, фильтры

У нас есть какой-то дата-сет.

И вот такой array с индексами:

```
Int64Index([70, 28, 9, 4, 72, 34, 52, 48, 37, 35, 14, 16, 18, 33, 40, 86, 47, 53],
           dtype='int64')
```

Как можно вывести дата-сет только с этими индексами?

Вроде `iloc` и `drop` нельзя передавать array.

Answer (score 3):

Используйте [`DataFrame.loc[]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) / [`DataFrame.iloc[]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html).

Исходный DataFrame:

```
In [128]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100,size=(100,3)), columns=list('abc'))

In [129]: df
Out[129]:
     a   b   c
0   74  99  10
1   17  47   4
2   43  48  12
3    4  41   6
4   48  87  91
5   15   7  66
6    1  81  44
7   19  46  26
8   66  41  53
9   83  66   9
..  ..  ..  ..
90   9  14  39
91  58  11  14
92  44  20  58
93  12  15  15
94  18  81  67
95  90  17  11
96  61   6  16
97  88  12  44
98  21  39  49
99  77  85  72

[100 rows x 3 columns]

In [130]: idx = pd.Int64Index([70, 28, 9, 4, 72, 34, 52, 48, 37, 35, 14, 16, 18, 33, 40, 86, 47, 53],dtype='int64')
```

Решение с `DataFrame.loc[]`:

```
In [131]: df.loc[idx]
Out[131]:
     a   b   c
70  61  50   5
28  97  65  38
9   83  66   9
4   48  87  91
72  91  65  98
34  83   4  44
52   8  68  15
48  55  17  26
37  56  61   8
35   1  29  12
14  96  12  18
16  44  35  74
18  69  65  24
33  57  55  51
40  55  15  40
86  85  81  38
47  14  27  27
53  57  50  77
```

Решение с `DataFrame.iloc[]`:

```
In [132]: df.iloc[idx]
Out[132]:
     a   b   c
70  61  50   5
28  97  65  38
9   83  66   9
4   48  87  91
72  91  65  98
34  83   4  44
52   8  68  15
48  55  17  26
37  56  61   8
35   1  29  12
14  96  12  18
16  44  35  74
18  69  65  24
33  57  55  51
40  55  15  40
86  85  81  38
47  14  27  27
53  57  50  77
```

**NOTE:** обратите внимание на различие в поведении `loc[]` и `iloc[]` - если значения индекса в DataFrame не совпадает с `np.arange(len(df))`, то результаты работы `df.loc[idx]` и `df.iloc[idx]` будут различаться.

Пример:

```
In [135]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100,size=(10,3)), 
                            columns=list('abc'), 
                            index=np.random.choice(range(10),10,replace=False))

In [136]: df
Out[136]:
    a   b   c
4  84  33  89
0  33  27  46
3  72  46  88
9  29  11   6
1  81  47   1
5  43  63  88
8  20  61  33
6  40  57  98
7   3  53  13
2  64  63  75

In [137]: idx = np.array([2,4,6])
```

---

```
In [138]: df.loc[idx]    # выбрать строки со значениями индекса [2,4,6]
Out[138]:
    a   b   c
2  64  63  75
4  84  33  89
6  40  57  98

In [139]: df.iloc[idx]   # выбрать строки с порядковыми номерами [2,4,6]
Out[139]:
    a   b   c
3  72  46  88
1  81  47   1
8  20  61  33
```